# Merge Many to many relationship with a one to one relationship

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a `Company` class with a list of `Sectors` and one `Main Sector` :

```
public class Company 
{
   public virtual List<Sector> Sectors {get; set;}
   [DisplayName("MainSectorId")]
   [ForeignKey("MainSector")]
   public virtual int? MainSectorId { get; set; }
   public virtual Sector MainSector { get; set; }
}

public class Sector
{
  public List<Company> Companies {get; set; }
}
```

the code first ignores the many to many relationship, the table `CompanySectors` was not created.

I fixed that by coding the table manually in the migration

```
    CreateTable(
        "dbo.CompanySectors",
        c => new
            {
                Company_Id = c.Int(nullable: false),
                Sector_Id = c.Int(nullable: false),
            })
        .PrimaryKey(t => new { t.Company_Id, t.Sector_Id })
        .ForeignKey("dbo.Companies", t => t.Company_Id, cascadeDelete: true)
        .ForeignKey("dbo.Sectors", t => t.Sector_Id, cascadeDelete: true)
        .Index(t => t.Company_Id)
        .Index(t => t.Sector_Id);
```

But the when I add a new sector to the company, the new sector is not inserted into the table `CompanySectors` :

```
        companyDB.MainSector = sectorDB;
        companyDB.MainSectorId = sectorDB.Id;
        EntityRepository.dbContext.Entry(companyDB).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
        EntityRepository.dbContext.Entry(sectorDB).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
        EntityRepository.dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

How can I have a many to many relation ship and a one to one  in the same table.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in making your navigation properties of type, `List<>`. They need to be `ICollection<>`. Once you fix that, Entity Framework will pick up the M2M and create the necessary join table. Adding the table manually, yourself, did nothing, because Entity Framework still had no knowledge of the relationship (as evidenced by the fact that it didn't create the table itself).

Comment: thanks for your answer, but what is the difference between List and ICollection, i mean why Entity framework don't create the join table if it is a list List<>, my code worked fine until i add a main sectors, i mean EF created the join table but when a added the main sector EF deleted my table :(

Comment: It's all pretty low-level, but simply a `List` requires immediately evaluation of the query, which conflicts with Entity Frameworks relationship handling.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work, even if I used ICollection instead of List.        EF created the join table correctly even if i used a List<>, but when i add the Main sector to the company like in the code bellow, the new migration deleted the join table :   public override void Up()
        {
            DropForeignKey("dbo.CompanySectors", "Company_Id", "dbo.Companies");
            DropForeignKey("dbo.CompanySectors", "Sector_Id", "dbo.Sectors");
            DropIndex("dbo.CompanySectors", new[] { "Company_Id" });
.........
            DropTable("dbo.CompanySectors");
        }